# Display elements at the bottom of a p:panel in PrimeFaces

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, panel, jsf-2.2

Given a `<p:panel>` as follows.

```
<p:panel style="height: 360px; width: 500px;" styleClass="panel-padding" header="Custom Measurements">
    <p:panelGrid columns="2" style="width: 100%;" styleClass="panelgrid-noborder">
        <p:outputLabel for="sleeveLength" value="Sleeve Length"/>
        <h:outputText id="sleeveLength" value="N/A" style="display: block; border: 1px dotted #999;"/>

        <p:outputLabel for="sleeveSize" value="Sleeve Size"/>
        <h:outputText id="sleeveSize" value="N/A" style="display: block; border: 1px dotted #999;"/>
    </p:panelGrid>

    <fieldset style="border:  1px dotted #999; bottom: 0; position: relative; margin: 9px;">
        <legend>
            <h:outputText value="Note" style="font-weight: bold;"/>
        </legend>
        Text goes here.
    </fieldset>
</p:panel>
```

The `<p:panelGrid>` inside the `<p:panel>` is completely irrelevant and can be excluded in its entirely.

Some CSS classes used (completely irrelevant and can be excluded) :

```css
.panelgrid-noborder.ui-panelgrid tr, .panelgrid-noborder.ui-panelgrid .ui-panelgrid-cell {
    border: none;
}

.panel-padding.ui-panel .ui-panel-content {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

The panel has a fixed height of `360px`. It looks like the following.

[image]

The `style` attribute of `<fieldset>` is one of the failed attempts of displaying it at the bottom of the panel.

How can I display the given HTML `<fieldset>` as indicated by the *note* box at the bottom of the panel (essentially a `<div>`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here,

```
<fieldset ... style="position: relative; bottom: 0;">
```

You used [`bottom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/bottom) property on a relatively [positioned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) element. From the linked documentation:

> For **relatively positioned elements**, that is, those with whose [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) property is set to `relative`, the `bottom` property specifies the distance the element's bottom edge is moved above its normal position.

Actually, you want to use a `bottom` property value of approximately `-180px`.

```
<fieldset ... style="position: relative; bottom: -180px;">
```

However, it's a bit strange to position the fieldset relatively in this context. Perhaps you want to position it absolutely, relative to the `<p:panel>`. In that case, this should do:

```
<p:panel ... style="position: relative;">

    <fieldset ... style="position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;">

    </fieldset>
</p:panel>
```

As per the documentation of the [`bottom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/bottom) property, that behaves then as follows, which is more logically in your particular markup and less likely to fail when there's more content in the fieldset:

> For **absolutely positioned elements**, that is, those whose [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) property is set to `absolute` or `fixed`, the `bottom` property specifies the distance between the bottom margin edge of the element and the bottom edge of the block containing the element.

Of course, refactor the `style` attributes to CSS classes in a real style sheet as soon as possible once you're done with fiddling around.